# How i can make that mobile menu fill the 50% of the width of the screen in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem after installed ["Mobile Navigation" Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-navigation/) to enable a mobile menu for my custom theme got fill the 100% of the width of the screen. So how I can make that mobile menu fill the 50% of the width of the screen like concept below?

[image: mobile menu]

**Here css for mobile menu**

```
 .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark [class*="icono-"] {
  color: #000; }

.mn-icon-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }
  .mn-icon-wrap:hover {
    cursor: pointer; }
  .mn-icon-wrap [class*="icono-"], .mn-icon-wrap [class*="icono-"] * {
    box-sizing: border-box; }
  .mn-icon-wrap [class*="icono-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    direction: ltr; }
  .mn-icon-wrap [class*="icono-"]:before,
  .mn-icon-wrap [class*="icono-"]:after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none; }
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-cross:before {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px; }
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-cross:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 2px; }
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-cross:before,
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-cross:after {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 5px; }
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-bars {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px,0 -6px,0 6px;
    margin: 16px 7px;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  .mn-icon-wrap .icono-cross {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); }

.mn-navigation-wrap {
  display: none;
  max-height: 60px;
  background: #000;
  background: #dd3333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000; }
  .mn-navigation-wrap.hidebar {
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-logo-text {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 24px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-logo-text a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: Georgia;
      font-family: ''; }
  .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-logo-image {
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-logo-image img {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto; }
  .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap {
    display: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-family: ''; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap ul {
      clear: both;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .sub-menu a {
      padding-left: 50px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .sub-menu .sub-menu a {
      padding-left: 80px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu a {
      padding-left: 110px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu a {
      padding-left: 140px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu a {
      padding-left: 170px; }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .current-menu-item > a,
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap .current_page_item > a {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); }
    .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap li a {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      display: block;
      list-style: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 1.5; }
      .mn-navigation-wrap .mn-menu-wrap li a:hover {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }
  .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark .mn-logo-text a {
    color: #000; }
  .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark .mn-menu-wrap li a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
    .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark .mn-menu-wrap li a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
  .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark .mn-menu-wrap .current-menu-item > a,
  .mn-navigation-wrap.mn-dark .mn-menu-wrap .current_page_item > a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  html {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 60px !important; }
    html body {
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important; }
    html.mn-open {
      overflow: hidden !important;
      background: #000;
      background: #dd3333; }
      html.mn-open body {
        overflow: hidden !important; }
      html.mn-open .mn-navigation-wrap {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10000;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #000;
        background: #dd3333; }
      html.mn-open .mn-menu-wrap {
        display: block; }
    html .mn-navigation-wrap {
      display: block; }
      html .mn-navigation-wrap.hidebar {
        max-height: 0; } }
```

For further detail please check out [my development url](http://dev.galerigadget.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really start using google chrome to inspect these things and work css out for yourself, the below is really basic stuff. The below needs to go into your stylesheet at the bottom

There are two issues, the red background is applied to html so remove that and then set the width element to the percentage value you want.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
   html.mn-open{
      background: none;
   }


   .mn-navigation-wrap{
       width: 50%; 
   }
}
```